# Redhat PostFix implementation - Temporary lookup failure

Tags: linux, email, postfix, redhat, smtp

Trying to set up PostFix as a simple relay server for apps and devices that need to send emails.  If in main.cf I set relayhost = [1.2.3.4] where 1.2.3.4 would be IP of my email spam filter (ProofPoint), **then everything is good and I can relay emails to external.**

What I need though is to set up rules where if send to domain example.com then send to our Office 365 smart host and then everything else get sent to Proofpoint smarthost.

I have set this up by

1. adding this in the main.cf:  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
2. adding these lines to the transport file:

   example.com      smtp:[365example_relay.com]

   *              smtp:1.2.3.4

With this in place though, when sending to test@example.com I get the error: "The server response was: 4.3.0 test@example.com: Temporary
lookup failure"

Same if I try to send to any other domain.

I don't believe an issue with DNS lookups because relaying works fine as long as I dont use transport_maps.

What am I missing here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/relay_by_sender &  postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```